# Error make test with mockery laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking

I'm trying to test a method of a class in my laravel project with mockery.
However, when I attempt to test the phpunit says a my interface class (which is being used in the method I need to test) is not instantiable.
What's wrong?

My test class

```
class HelperRSTest extends TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
      Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_mockery()
    {
        // $mock = Mockery::mock('HelperRS');
        // $mock->shouldReceive('getRecibosLocacao')->once()->andReturn('mocked');

        $result = HelperRS::getRecibosLocacao(1228);
        var_dump($result);
    }

}
```

My target class to test

```
class HelperRS extends \BaseController {

    public static function getRecibosLocacao($id_locacao){

        $pagamentos = App::make('PagamentoRepositoryInterface');

        $locacao = Locacao::find($id_locacao);
        $pagamento = $pagamentos->getByVendaByTipo($locacao->cod_locacao, 'l');

        dd($pagamento);

    }

}
```

The error:

```
1) HelperRSTest::test_mockery
Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [PagamentoRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are calling on HelperRS is a static method, whereas you are creating a mocked instance of that class and not actually doing anything with it. You can achieve this with mockery, though it is not recommended and will require you to run the test in process isolation.

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('alias:HelperRS');
$mock->shouldReceive('getRecibosLocacao')->once()->andReturn('mocked');
```

Comment: I'm new to unit-tests. How would run the test in an isolated process? I really can test statics methods?

Comment: This process "Mockery::mock('something')", I always need to do this before the start tests? It can not be done at runtime?

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz Use the \@runInSeparateProcess annotation to run a test with process isolation and you should be fine calling Mockery::mock during the test